# CircleCI Tests Run Twice

Tags: unit-test, circleci

I am running CI using Circle CI.  Here is my config.yml:

```
version: 2.1
general:
jobs:
  build:
    machine:
      image: ubuntu-2004:202201-02
    resource_class: large
    working_directory: ~/ci_app
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Install CLI
          command: |
            node --version
            npm install sfdx-cli --global
            sfdx --version
      - run:
          name: Create hub key
          command: |
            echo 'make hub key'
            openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in .circleci/server.key.enc -out .circleci/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPTION_KEY -iv $DECRYPTION_IV
      - run:
          name: Setup Org
          command: |
            echo 'Create/Push'
            ls -al
            pwd
            echo 'Here we go!'
            sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY --jwtkeyfile .circleci/server.key --username $HUB_SFDC_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub            
            sfdx force:org:create -s -f .circleci/project-scratch-def.json -a circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM --wait 4 -d 1
            sfdx force:source:push -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM 
      - run:
          name: Run Apex Tests
          no_output_timeout: 30m
          command: |
            mkdir -p ~/junit
            sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -d ~/junit -r junit --wait 30
      - store_test_results:
          # if: always()
          path: ~/junit
      - run:
          name: Delete Useless Scratch Org
          # if: always()
          command: |
            sfdx force:org:delete -u circle_build_$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM -p
```

Here is my question:  The Apex unit tests run TWICE for some reason.  Why?  Thanks.

Output for running ONE unit test class.  Again double display of tests:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mkdir -p ~/junit
# sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -d ~/junit -r junit --wait 30
sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -d ~/junit -r junit --wait 30 -n "UnitTestsBusinessLogic7"

WARNING: WARNING: In the Summer ’21 release, we'll rename or remove some of the output files that are created when you run force:apex:test:run or force:apex:test:report with the --outputdir (-d) parameter.  This breaking change could impact your CI/CD scripts if they reference specific filenames. See https://sfdc.co/apex-test-updates for details

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="force.apex" timestamp="2022-04-19T19:00:26.000Z" hostname="https://innovation-site-6782-dev-ed.cs78.my.salesforce.com" tests="31" failures="7"  errors="0"  time="40.16">
        <properties>
            <property name="outcome" value="Failed"/>
            <property name="testsRan" value="31"/>
            <property name="passing" value="24"/>
            <property name="failing" value="7"/>
            <property name="skipped" value="0"/>
            <property name="passRate" value="77%"/>
            <property name="failRate" value="23%"/>
            <property name="testStartTime" value="Tue Apr 19 2022 7:00:26 PM"/>
            <property name="testExecutionTime" value="40.16 s"/>
            <property name="testTotalTime" value="40.16 s"/>
            <property name="commandTime" value="0.14 s"/>
            <property name="hostname" value="https://innovation-site-6782-dev-ed.cs78.my.salesforce.com"/>
            <property name="orgId" value="00D1k0000007IRtEAM"/>
            <property name="username" value="test-tsjlt9ht1ayh@example.com"/>
            <property name="testRunId" value="7071k0000267UQu"/>
            <property name="userId" value="0051k000008F0ZrAAK"/>
            <property name="coveredLines" value="4539"/>
            <property name="testRunCoverage" value="25%"/>
            <property name="orgWideCoverage" value="6%"/>
        </properties>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument1" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.18">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument10" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="3.60">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument11" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.98">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument2" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.09">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument3" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.84">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument4" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.09">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument5" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.03">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument6" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.66">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument7" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.22">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument8" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.10">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testCustomerInvoiceDocument9" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="2.12">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadImporter" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.38">
            <failure message="System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: testLoadImporter failed: Expected: 15, Actual: 0"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadImporter: line 726, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadPricingWorkbench1" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.78">
            <failure message="System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 12"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadPricingWorkbench1: line 775, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadPricingWorkbench4" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.61">
            <failure message="System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 12"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadPricingWorkbench4: line 902, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadPricingWorkbench5" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.53">
            <failure message="System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 12"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadPricingWorkbench5: line 945, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadPricingWorkbench6" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.51">
            <failure message="System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 12"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadPricingWorkbench6: line 987, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation1" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.82">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation2" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.92">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation3" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.94">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation4" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.16">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation5" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.35">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation6" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.00">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation7" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.08">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculation8" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.99">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testRateCalculationResult1" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.12">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testTMSDocumentOverrides1" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.72">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testTMSRateIQService1" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.11">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testTMSRateIQService2" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.01">
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadPricingWorkbench2" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.53">
            <failure message="System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 12"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadPricingWorkbench2: line 816, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testLoadPricingWorkbench3" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="0.62">
            <failure message="System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 12"><![CDATA[Class.UnitTestsBusinessLogic7.testLoadPricingWorkbench3: line 857, column 1]]></failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testTMSRateIQService3" classname="UnitTestsBusinessLogic7" time="1.08">
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>


Exited with code exit status 100
CircleCI received exit code 100
```

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the console output?

Comment: Sure.  I have added a run where only one test class is executed.  The tests in that one class appear to execute twice.  There are 31 tests but the app is saying there are 62.  There are 7 failures but the app is saying 14.

Comment: Hello Dave - could you please explain what do you mean by double display when running ONE unit test class? I could not find duplicates test classes being executed on the file you shared.

Comment: As Jefferson notes - the file output from sfdx doesn't appear to have duplicates, but CircleCI test tab appears to be displaying duplicates in a way that makes it seem like it's stored the results twice. Have you tried to change anything? Ex. different output format (json) or re-arrange steps to have `store_test_output` to see if the behavior changes?

Comment: Are you certain that the tests are actually getting run twice, as opposed to something causing the output from one run of tests to appear twice? (I know nothing of CircleCI - just spitballing.)

Comment: What happens if you comment out the Store Test Results step? See if that makes a difference

Comment: @BryanAnderson : That's sort of what I was thinking when I asked my question. But not being familiar with CircleCI, I didn't know whether `store_test_results` was just a section label or is a function/command.

Comment: Have you verified that there are two separate XML files (or sets thereof) in your `/junit` folder after CircleCI runs?

Comment: Excellent advice, all!  Let me try this and get back to you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation (https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/collect-test-data/):

> Using the `store_test_results` step allows you to not only upload and store test results, but also provides a view of your passing/failing tests in the CircleCI web app.

Not knowing the inner workings of CircleCI, I am surmising that the view that comes with the `store_test_results` step essentially just parses whatever it finds in that `path` folder.

---

To test my hypothesis, on my local machine in VS Code I created a scratch org, pushed code, and then ran the following command:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -r junit -d ./junit --wait 30
```

Here is what is in that `junit` folder after the run:
[image]

Notice that there are two XML files.

I did a diff of the two and they are exactly the same.

---

Here is what I suspect is happening in your case:

- Your `sfdx force:apex:test:run` command run is automatically saving in your `-d ~/junit` folder two XML files that have the same data
- The view parser that comes with using `store_test_results` in CircleCI is showing everything from all XML files in that folder

So I think that your tests are not running twice, you are just viewing duplicate outputs.

---

Again, not knowing CircleCI, I'm not certain of all your options; but the first two potential ones that pop into my mind are:

- See if you can add any parameter/option/config to your `store_test_results` step that would have it look at only one file named `test-result.xml`.
- Add a step after your test run and before `store_test_results` that EITHER

  - deletes or moves all other files except `test-result.xml`; OR
  - moves only `test-result.xml` to a separate folder, and then point `store_test_results` to that folder

---

#### UPDATE

"On a hunch" I changed the result format of the `sfdx` test run from `junit` to `json`.  After running, my hunch was confirmed as here are the contents of the output folder:

[image]

Notice that the XML file which includes the `test-run-id` in the filename is still being generated (along with a few other of the same non-XML files) regardless of the result format chosen.

I compared that file to both XMLs that I mentioned earlier, and it looks like the same contents.

So if my hypothesis is correct about CircleCI parsing whatever XML files it finds in the `path` folder, then you could quickly and simply test it by changing your test run line to:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -c -r json -d ./junit --wait 30
```

*(Or for that matter, you could use `human` instead of `json` and get a (mostly) nicely formatted more readable text file to go along with that one XML that always seems to get generated.)*

Now if it works, you would then have to decide whether to permanently leave it like that in your script. Sure it would be an easy fix, but would that be confusing to someone else (or a future you) trying to maintain/update this script? It *might* be OK to leave it if you document it well. That would be your call.

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the excellent help!  Especially thanks to Moonpie.  I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: Updated with additional findings.